# Where are "headers" for other languages kept?

Tags: linux, directory-structure, header-file

If I were to write a library for a C-incompatible language (like D), where would be the best place to install my "header files" to?

`usr/include` seems like a bad idea, since the FHS says it's for "header files included by C programs."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define your own conventions, but I'd indeed stay away from `/usr/include`.

`/usr/lib/<lang>` seems popular here for interpreted languages (I've at least `/usr/lib/python`, `/usr/lib/perl` and `/usr/lib/ruby` with variants for the handling of version specific stuff) I think that `/usr/share/<lang>` is more proper from the FHS (I've also `/usr/share/tcl` with a symbolic link from `/usr/lib/tcl`) if there is no binary data there (or at least only architecture independent binary data).

Still in the FHS spirit, I'd tend to use `/opt/<lang>/share` or `/opt/<lang>/lib` while providing the installer (or the distribution) an easy way to use `/usr/share/<lang>` or `/usr/lib/<lang>`.

Comment: I'd say '/usr/lib/<lang>/include'. 1+

Answer (score 0):

I'd say `/usr/local/include/` for your own additions. [Linux Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard)